# Trying to delay an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hello im trying to delay my Ajax call to get my value, as it relies on another script to complete.  It's a simple cart icon that has a total.   I have tried this,  but it does not work.

```
document.addEventListener("click", cartItemTotal);
function cartItemTotal() {

  var delay = 500;
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("UpdateCartCount").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
    }, delay);
  }
  xhttp.open("POST", "items.php");
  xhttp.send();   
}
```

any ideas what im doing wrong?  thanks

Comment: your `setTimeout` function is in the `onreadystatechange` handler. you dont delay the ajax request, you delay the handling of the state-changes...

Comment: thank you !  appreciate your time to look and correct my issue.

Comment: This will never work reliably. You need your other script to call the Ajax function or some callback function etc. Anything that is _reliable_. You never know if there are network issues, processing issues, etc. There are plenty of ways that would make your other script not ready before the timeout fires. Not to mention that users are impatient. If you wait half a second, users might simply click again and again as "nothing is happening when I click".

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  You are right, but, the next time they click anywhere it will try again to update the total.  It's not for a production site.